# how to get updated .env values in python?

Tags: python, python-dotenv

file structure:

```
|_ login.py
|_ main.py
|_ .env
```

`login.py` has function called `login()` that logs user in and sets token in .env file. `.env` file gets updated, but when I try to access the new updated token in `main.py` it gives me old token.

login.py:

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, set_key

dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

creds = {
    'token': os.environ.get('TOKEN', ''),
    'username': os.environ.get('USERNAME', ''),
    'password': os.environ.get('PASSWORD', ''),
    'base_url': os.environ.get('BASE_URL', '')
}

def api_login():
    req = requests.post(creds).json()
    set_key(dotenv_path, 'token', req.get('token')
```

main.py:

```py
import os
import requests

from dotenv import load_dotenv

from login import login

dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

creds = {
    'token': os.environ.get('TOKEN', ''),
    'username': os.environ.get('USERNAME', ''),
    'password': os.environ.get('PASSWORD', ''),
    'base_url': os.environ.get('BASE_URL', '')
}


def make_request():
    if creds['token'] == '':
        login()
    print(os.environ.get('TOKEN', ''))
```

The only way I am able to get new token is if I store value in `os.environ['temp_token'] = req.get('token')` in `login()` and access it `os.environ['temp_token']` in `main.py`. The other way is to make `login()` return the new token.

Is there a way you can get updated values from `.env` file?

Comment: Does `main.py` call code from `login.py`? I am not sure why do you need a `.env` file.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I am storing user credentials in .env file. main.py calls login function from login.py to get new token if existing token is expired or is set to empty string.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you just keep the token in memory and always read it from there? If you still want to persist it to a file, that file could be read just once at the beggining and written whenever you log in again.